# Should I re-ask a question if the answer is incorrect?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I am trying to find an answer to a specific problem, and I see that someone has already posted the exact same question two years ago. The question has a single answer, which has been accepted - however the answer given is wrong.

I still need an answer. Is it OK to ask a duplicate question in this case? If not, what else can I do?

Comment: What do you mean *"wrong"*? Won't run? Wrong for your particular situation? In general, don't ask a duplicate - consider adding a bounty to draw more attention.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Does it make a difference? Is there some case when a duplicate is correct and another where it is not?

Comment: Yes, of course it does - if it worked for the OP but your situation is slightly different somehow, then **mention that in your question**. Say that you've read that question (include a link) and be specific about how yours differs. Perhaps you are using a different version of the software, for example. However, if the answer is somehow broken or incomplete, that's a slightly different scenario.

Answer (score 8):

No, don't ask a duplicate question. You have plenty of reputation to post a bounty asking for better answers.

Comment: Good idea! Somehow I forgot I could do that.